# Getting BDD test to block/wait before proceeding

Tags: c#, bdd

I am having issues executing a series of BDD steps with a while loop.
Goal is to answer all of the questions the web app I am testing asks.

total questions is obtained from the app before user starts answering questions.  After answer is selected and next clicked index increments.

Due to timing issues this has been a huge pain.  Thread.Sleep is not an option.

I thought using Polly it would not increment index until both clicks succeed.  This is not the case and my test scenario bails.

Any thoughts or suggestions will be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

```
var policy = Policy.Handle<WebDriverException>()
             .WaitAndRetry(3, retryAttempt =>
             TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
             (exception, timeSpan) =>
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Encountered exception {0}",exception.Message);
             });

while (index <= totalQuestions)
        {

           Console.WriteLine(index);
           policy.Execute(() => Control<Label>("Choice 1", "DashboardNavigator").ClickByJS());
           policy.Execute(() => Control<Label>("Siguiente", "DashboardNavigator").ClickByJS());
           index++;
        }
```

The index just runs away and the while loop breaks before all questions have been answered.

Comment: What is the behaviour of `.ClickByJs()`?  Does it block until whatever you are seeking to test succeeds?  Does it return `void` or a `Task`?  How does it indicate failure?

Comment: Without more info re `ClickByJS()`, hard to help. Any `Console.Writeline` output? If not, no `WebDriverException` occurs. What makes `Control` or `ClickByJS()` throw `WebDriverException`s? From your description of racing through, sounds like `ClickByJS()` perhaps simply returns fast & without exception. If `ClickByJS()` returns `Task`, use `await policy.ExecuteAsync(...)`. Polly usage standard: would not expect Polly to be at fault here. How are you expecting Polly to help? Sounds like expecting it help underlying interface 'move on' to next q somehow? By what mechanism? Need more info to help

Comment: Sounds like you may be expecting `ClickByJS()` to block in some way it doesn't, or exhibit some behaviour/meet some requirement before returning, that it doesn't.  What do you mean by "click succeeds"? What do you expect / hope / need to have happened before `ClickByJS()` returns? (or before the next loop invocation is made?).  I would focus on assumptions around `ClickByJS()`. ... Or: could the loop simply be succeeding in clicking the first question each time round the loop? Polly won't make it slower in any relevant way, if `ClickByJS()` returns fast.